# How to determine all subgroups of $Q_{20}$ (The generalised quaternion group of order $20$), and to indicate normal ones?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

By Lagrange's, the subgroups have orders $20$ ($Q_{20}$ itself), $10$, $5$, $4$, $2$, and $1$ (the identity subgroup). For example, a subgroup of order $10$ has elements of order $5$ and $2$ by Cauchy's. I have determined the orders of the elements, I'm just not very sure how to find those subgroups.
$Q_{20}=\langle a,b:a^{10}=1,b^2=a^5,ba=a^{-1}b\rangle$
Thanks

Comment: Could you link to a definition of the quaternion group of order $20$? I am only familiar with the ones of order a power of $2$.

Comment: $Q_{20}=<a,b:a^{10}=1,b^2=a^5,ba=a^{-1}b>$

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: GAP tells that, the group is isomorphic with $C_5:C_4$

Comment: @subzero155: In the generalized quaternion group, the power of $a$ is the power of $2$. I mean it is $2^{n-1}$ when working on $Q_{n}$. I follow the Rotman's notation.

Comment: @BabakS.I have defined the group above. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion_group#Generalized_quaternion_group for more derails.

Comment: @BabakS., did you mean the group is isomorphic with a semidirect product $\,C_4\rtimes C_5\;$ ? Or what does that notation $\,C_5:C_4\;$ mean?

Comment: @DonAntonio That is the way GAP denotes a semidirect product.

Comment: I see, @TobiasKildetoft . Thanks

Comment: That notation is also used for certain split extensions in a lot of finite group theory literature.

Comment: @subzero155: Have you ever trying GAP for your purposes? I, completely, agree with Don's second comment below.

Comment: @BabakS. I just did for the sake of the question. Not very good at it though. But I know there are 10 subgroups and I have determined them by exhaustion.

Comment: @subzero155: Oh, I see. Great job! and +1 :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An idea:

We take your presentation for the group (but check the added part for $\,b^4\;$. Just to have a standard presentation):

$$Q_{20}=\left\langle a\,,\,b\;;\;a^{10}=b^4=1\;,\;b^2=a^5\;,\;bab^{-1}=a^{-1}\right\rangle\;,\;\;\text{then}$$

$$\begin{align*}H_2:=&\langle a^5\rangle\;\;&\text{ has order}\;\;2\\
H_4:=&\langle b\rangle \;\;&\text{has order}\;\;4\\
H_5:=&\langle a^2\rangle\;\;&\text{has order}\;\;5\\
H_{10}:=&\langle a\rangle\;\;&\text{has order }\;\;10\end{align*}$$

Comment: $b^4=1$ is a direct consequence of $a^{10}=1$ and $b^2=a^5$. These are not all subgroups.

Comment: No...I never mentioned nor hinted these are "all" the groups. These are just **some** examples of subgroups with the orders you mentioned. For example, you can check *that also*  $\,\left|\,\langle ab\rangle\,\right|=4\;$ ...

Comment: Yes I understand. Just wandering how I can find them all and make sure that they are all.

Comment: I see...I don't know whether there's a standard method to write down the complete subgroup lattice of a general group, *even* of a finite one. Perhaps in this particular case something can be done. Anyway, check here:http://www.fredonia.edu/department/math/facultypages/straight/groups/pdf/groups20.pdf

Comment: I don't think there is a standard way of finding them. I guess only by exhaustion.

Comment: Yup...in the link I wrote you there's the whole subgroup lattice of $\,G\,$ and, perhaps (didn't check) some explanations on how to do that in a more or less systematic way.